# how to remove these errors in my tex presentation slides?

Tags: beamer, errors

Can somebody help in removing errors from this file?

```
  \documentclass[10pt,xcolor=svgnames]{beamer}
%\documentclass{article}

%usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{geometry}
%\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\colorlet{white}{white}
\mode<presentation>
% 

%
%\usetheme{Dresden}
%\usecolortheme{beaver}
%\setbeamercolor{itemize item}{fg=darkred!80!white}
%
%\usetheme{Singapore}
% \usetheme{Boadilla}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%\usepackage{BeamerColor}
%\usetheme[]{Szeged}
%\The new themes are Warsaw, Boadilla, AnnArbor,Rochester,Antibes,JuanLesPins,Berlin,rounded,crane
%\usetheme[]{Szeged}
%\usetheme{Pittsburgh}
%\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
%\usetheme[hoptionsi]{Berkeley}
%\usecolortheme[]{wolverine}
%\usetheme[]{Berkeley}
%\usetheme{dresden}
%\usefonttheme{structureitalicserif}
\usetheme{Antibes}
%\usecolortheme{crane}
%\usetheme[]{}
%\usecolortheme[named=OliveGreen]{structure}
%\usecolortheme[named=Brown]{structure}
%\usecolortheme[named=OliveGreen]{structure}
%\usecolortheme{wolverine}
%\usecolortheme{oily}
%\setbeamerfont{}{size={50cm}}
\setbeamertemplate{enumerate items}[default]
\setbeamertemplate{theorems}[ams style]
\usepackage{ragged2e}\justifying
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{epsf}
%\usepackage{graphics}
%\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{cor}[theorem]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{Algorithm}[theorem]{Algorithm}
\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}
\newtheorem{remark}[theorem]{Remark}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\newcommand{\Date}{3 october 2019}% change the date here
\newcommand{\companyName}{Company Name Here} % change company name here
\newcommand{\Speaker}{Speaker} %change speaker name with 'speaker'
\newcommand{\SpeakerTitle}{Speaker's Title} %change speaker title with "Speaker's Title"
\title[company name]
{\LARGE \textbf{company name}}

\subtitle{}

\author[ABCD]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.25,0.00}{ABCD}}

\institute[]
{\inst{}%
 ABC Uni

}
%
\date[]{ }
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%\documentclass{beamer}
\useoutertheme{split}
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[page number]
\pagestyle{plain}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\usepackage{beamerthemeshadow}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\rfoot{\thepage}

\begin{document}

%\begin{frame}
%  \titlepage
%\end{frame} 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% FRAME 2 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%\bgroup
\usebackgroundtemplate{
    \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{1.png}} 
    \begin{frame}
  \tikz[remember picture, overlay] \fill[green] (current page.south west) rectangle ++(\paperwidth,0.27cm); %Draw green line at the bottom of the page

    \vspace*{-0.5in} %adjust this if your logo is being cropped from top
    \begin{flushleft}
        {\includegraphics[width=5cm]{2.png}}
        \vspace{-0.8cm}
        \newgeometry{textwidth = 5cm} % change it if you change the width of the logo
        \begin{flushright}
        {\textcolor{white}{A tagline for the company spans}}\\
        {\textcolor{white}{two lines just under the logo.}} \\
    \end{flushright}
        \vspace{-0.7cm}
        \newgeometry{textwidth = 5cm} % change it if you change the width of the logo
        \begin{flushright}
        {\textcolor{white}{\Date}}
        \end{flushright}
    \end{flushleft}


    \restoregeometry
%\textcolor{white}{\text{A tagline for the company \\ 
%spans two lines just under the logo}} 
%\vfill
\begin{columns}%beamer
    \column{0.45\textwidth}
    % blank
    \column{0.45\textwidth}
    \begin{flushleft}
        \begin{tcolorbox}[standard jigsaw, opacityback = 0, top =2cm, left = 0 cm, colframe=white, width = 4.5cm]
            \textcolor{white}{\textbf{CLICK TO ADD TITLE}}
        \end{tcolorbox}
        \textcolor{white}{\Speaker, \SpeakerTitle}
    \end{flushleft}

\end{columns}
%\section{1}
%\textcolor{white}{click to add title}
    \end{frame}

%\egroup
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% FRAME 3 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{frame}
\tikz[remember picture, overlay] \fill[green] (current page.south west) rectangle ++(\paperwidth,0.27cm); %Draw green line at the bottom of the page

\section{Open Ball, Closed Ball, Sphere}\label{1114}
\begin{flushleft}
\vbox{
    \begin{minipage}[t][0.0025\textheight][t]{\textwidth}
        \tiny{\companyName $ |$ \Date}
    \end{minipage}\\

    \begin{minipage}[b][0.2\textheight][b]{0.95\textwidth}
        \begin{tcolorbox}[standard jigsaw, opacityback = 0, top =0.5cm, bottom = 0.5cm, left = 0 cm, colframe=black]
    \textbf{CLICK TO ADD TITLE} %Edit this if you just want to change the text, else if you want to remove complete box then delete the block of "tcolorbox" and start writting required text
    \end{tcolorbox}
    \end{minipage}\\

    \begin{minipage}[t][0.5\textheight][t]{0.95\textwidth}
        \begin{tcolorbox}[standard jigsaw, opacityback = 0, bottom =2in , left = 0 cm, colframe=black]
    \textbf{CLICK TO ADD TITLE} %Edit this if you just want to change the text, else if you want to remove complete box then delete the block of "tcolorbox" and start writting required text
    \end{tcolorbox}
    \end{minipage}
    \begin{picture}(25, 30)(-293, -215)
    \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{3.png}
    \end{picture}
}
\end{flushleft}

\end{frame}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% FRAME 4 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%\bgroup
\usebackgroundtemplate{%
    \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{1.png}} 
\begin{frame}
\tikz[remember picture, overlay] \fill[green] (current page.south west) rectangle ++(\paperwidth,0.27cm); %Draw green line at the bottom of the page
    \vspace*{-1in} %adjust this if your logo is being cropped from top
    \begin{flushleft}
        {\includegraphics[width=5cm]{2.png}}
            \vspace{-0.75cm}
        \newgeometry{textwidth = 5cm} % change it if you change the width of the logo
        \begin{flushright}
        {\textcolor{white}{A tagline for the company spans}}\\
        {\textcolor{white}{two lines just under the logo.}} \\
    \end{flushright}
        \vspace{-0.6cm}
        \newgeometry{textwidth = 5cm} % change it if you change the width of the logo
        \begin{flushright}
        {\textcolor{white}{\Date}}
        \end{flushright}
    \end{flushleft}
    \restoregeometry

%\textcolor{white}{\text{A tagline for the company \\ 
%spams two lines just under the logo}} 
%\vfill
\begin{columns}%beamer
    \column{0.45\textwidth}
    % blank
    \column{0.45\textwidth}
    \begin{flushleft}
        \vspace{0.9cm}
    \textcolor{white}{\textbf{QUESTIONS?}}\\
    \vspace{0.2cm}
    \textcolor{white}{\Speaker, \SpeakerTitle}
    \end{flushleft}

\end{columns}
%   \section{1}
\thispagestyle{empty}

    \end{frame}
%\egroup
\end{document}
```

Comment: Replace `\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}` with `\documentclass[10pt,xcolor=svgnames]{beamer}` and remove `\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}`. Also remove the `graphicx` and `graphics` packages from your preamble.

Comment: Hi leandrils its not working :(

Comment: Your file still contains a lot more errors but my above comment should at least fix some of them.

Comment: yes dear thanks alot for your help. but please chk these errors and help me out please.

Comment: i have updated the code above.

Comment: Errors are:  Undefined control sequence. \end{frame} on line 142 and line 215

Comment: There is no package in your preamble that defines `\subcaptionbox`. Please explain the purpose of `\subcaptionbox` in the context of the presentation.I would espect this to be used to add a caption to a subfigure. However, this does not seem to be the case in your example.

Comment: Please also explain the purpose of the `flushright` /`flushleft` environments as well as the `\newgeometry{textwidth = 5cm}` and `\restoregeometry` commands.

Comment: flush left and right are used to move object to the left or right side of the page

Comment: @leandriis Thank you soooooooooooooo much. All errors got removed by removing \subcaptionbox from each line. :-) You are great master ..

Comment: Now please check this 1 warnings bad box >>>>          Overfull \vbox (19.93971pt too high) detected –

Comment: The overfull \vbox warning is cause by something being too large for the available space. Probably it is caused by (one of ) the images but this is hard to tell since they are not available.